# Subset DF with for-loop to run each subset through a function

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a data set of plant demographics from 5 years across 10 sites with a total of 37 transects within the sites. Below is a link to a GoogleDoc with some of the data:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VT-dDrTwG8wHBNx7eW4BtXH5wqesnIDwKTdK61xsD0U/edit?usp=sharing

In total, I have 101 unique combinations.

I need to subset each unique set of data, so that I can run each through some code. This code will give me one column of output that I need to add back to the original data frame so that I can run LMs on the entire data set. I had hoped to write a for-loop where I could subset each unique combination, run the code on each, and then append the output for each model back onto the original dataset. My attempts at writing a subset loop have all failed to produce even a simple output.

I created a column, "SiteTY", with unique Site, Transect, Year combinations. So "PWR 832015" is site PWR Transect 83 Year 2015. I tried to use that to loop through and fill an empty matrix, as proof of concept.

```
transect=unique(dat$SiteTY)
ntrans=length(transect)
tmpout=matrix(NA, nrow=ntrans, ncol=2)

for (i in 1:ntrans) {
   df=subset(dat, SiteTY==i)
   tmpout[i,]=(unique(df$SiteTY))
}
```

When I do this, I notice that df has no observations. If I replace "i" with a known value (like PWR 832015) and run each line of the for-loop individually, it populates correctly. If I use is.factor() for i or PWR 832015, both return FALSE.
This particular code also gives me the error:

> Error in `[,-`(`*tmp*`, , i, value=mean(df$Year)) : subscript out of bounds

I can only assume this happens because the data frame is empty.
I've read enough SO posts to know that for-loops are tricky, but I've tried more iterations than I can remember to try to make this work in the last 3 years to no avail.

Any tips on loops or ways to avoid them while getting the output I need would be appreciated.

Comment: NOTE: I am posting this without the ability to add my data at the moment. I will be adding example data this evening as soon as I'm able.

Comment: I guess sitetv is not integer but i is...

Comment: You should add data with `dput(head(my_data,10))`. 10 is a random choice. Otherwise, better to post the question with some sample data that mimics your data set.

Comment: Try with `for (i in transect )`. The values themselves are not equal to their index positions.

Comment: I have tried (i in transect) but it returns a new error "no 'dimnames' attribute for array and the matrix is filled with "NA"

Comment: @NelsonGon sample data have been added.

Answer (score 1):

Per your needs, *I need to subset each unique set of data, run a function, take the output and calculate a new value*, consider two routes:

1. Using `ave` if your function expects and returns a single numeric column.
2. Using `by` if your function expects a data frame and returns anything.

**`ave`**

Returns a grouped inline aggregate column with repeated value for every member of group. Below, `with` is used as context manager to avoid repeated `dat$` references.

```
# BY SITE GROUPING
dat$New_Column <- with(dat, ave(Numeric_Column, Site, FUN=myfunction))

# BY SITE AND TRANSECT GROUPINGS
dat$New_Column <- with(dat, ave(Numeric_Column, Site, Transect, FUN=myfunction))

# BY SITE AND TRANSECT AND YEAR GROUPINGS
dat$New_Column <- with(dat, ave(Numeric_Column, Site, Transect, Year, FUN=myfunction))
```

**`by`**

Returns a named list of objects or whatever your function returns for each possible grouping. For more than one grouping, `tryCatch` is used due to possibly empty data frame item from all possible combinations where your *myfunction* can return an error.

```
# BY SITE GROUPING
obj_list <- by(dat, dat$Site, function(sub) {    
        myfunction(sub)  # RUN ANY OPERATION ON sub DATA FRAME
})

# BY SITE AND TRANSECT GROUPINGS
obj_list <- by(dat, dat[c("Site", "Transect")], function(sub) {    
        tryCatch(myfunction(sub),
                 error = function(e) NULL)
})

# BY SITE AND TRANSECT AND YEAR GROUPINGS
obj_list <- by(dat, dat[c("Site", "Transect", "Year")], function(sub) {    
        tryCatch(myfunction(sub),
                 error = function(e) NULL)
})

# FILTERS OUT ALL NULLs (I.E., NO LENGTH)
obj_list <- Filter(length, obj_list)

# BUILDS SINGLE OUTPUT IF MATRIX OR DATA FRAME
final_obj <- do.call(rbind, obj_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach using the `dplyr` library, in which I'm creating a data.frame of summary statistics for each group and then just joining it back on:

```
library(dplyr)

# Group by species (site, transect, etc) and summarise
species_summary <- iris %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    summarise(mean.Sepal.Length = mean(Sepal.Length),
              mean.Sepal.Width = mean(Sepal.Width))

# A data.frame with one row per species, one column per statistic
species_summary

# Join the summary stats back onto the original data
iris_plus <- iris %>% left_join(species_summary, by = "Species")

head(iris_plus)
```